# How to fix a Table view cell title text overlap each when it is scrolled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view and when it scrolls the cell title text overlap each other.

[image]

I'm I setting up the cellForIndexPath: incorrectly?

here's my cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ 
    BOOL isLandscape = YES;
    if (nextOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || nextOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        isLandscape = NO;
    }
    UIImageView* bgImage;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(isLandscape) ? @"landscape-cell":@"portrait-cell"]; 
    if (cell == nil){
     //   cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:(isLandscape) ? @"landscape-cell":@"portrait-cell"] autorelease];

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:(isLandscape)  ? @"landscape-cell":@"portrait-cell"] autorelease];


        if (isLandscape) {
            bgImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 125)] autorelease];
            [bgImage setTag:BACK_IMAGE];
//          
            [cell addSubview:bgImage];

        }else {
            bgImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 125)] autorelease];
            [bgImage setTag:BACK_IMAGE];
            [cell addSubview:bgImage];

        }


    }else {
        bgImage = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:BACK_IMAGE];
    }
    for (UIView* v in cell.subviews) {
        if ([v isKindOfClass:[CatalogeView class]]) {
            [v removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    if (isLandscape) {
        if (IPADAPP) {
            [bgImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 250)];
            [bgImage setImage:[ImgUtil image:@"polka_gor@2x.png"]];
            int num = 0;
            for(int i = indexPath.row*CATALOGE_ON_SHELF_HORIZONTAL; i < [cataloges count] && i < (indexPath.row + 1)*CATALOGE_ON_SHELF_HORIZONTAL; i++){
                CatalogeView* catalogeView = [cataloges objectAtIndex:i];
                [catalogeView setPosition:CGPointMake(40 + 120*(num%CATALOGE_ON_SHELF_HORIZONTAL) * 2 , 30)];
                [cell addSubview:catalogeView];
                num++;
            }

        }else{

            [bgImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 125)];
            [bgImage setImage:[ImgUtil image:@"polka_gor.png"]];
            int num = 0;
            for(int i = indexPath.row*CATALOGE_ON_SHELF_HORIZONTAL; i < [cataloges count] && i < (indexPath.row + 1)*CATALOGE_ON_SHELF_HORIZONTAL; i++){
                CatalogeView* catalogeView = [cataloges objectAtIndex:i];
                [catalogeView setPosition:CGPointMake(20 + 120*(num%CATALOGE_ON_SHELF_HORIZONTAL),15)];
                [cell addSubview:catalogeView];
                num++;
            }

        }

    }else {
        if (IPADAPP) {
            [bgImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 250)];
            [bgImage setImage:[ImgUtil image:@"polka@2x.png"]];
            int num = 0;
            for(int i = indexPath.row*CATALOGE_ON_SHELF_VERTICAL; i < [cataloges count] && i < (indexPath.row + 1)*CATALOGE_ON_SHELF_VERTICAL; i++){
                CatalogeView* catalogeView = [cataloges objectAtIndex:i];
                [catalogeView setPosition:CGPointMake(20 + 105*(num%CATALOGE_ON_SHELF_VERTICAL) * 2.5 ,30)];
                [cell addSubview:catalogeView];
                num++;
            }

        }else{
            [bgImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 125)];
            [bgImage setImage:[ImgUtil image:@"polka.png"]];
            int num = 0;
            for(int i = indexPath.row*CATALOGE_ON_SHELF_VERTICAL; i < [cataloges count] && i < (indexPath.row + 1)*CATALOGE_ON_SHELF_VERTICAL; i++){
                CatalogeView* catalogeView = [cataloges objectAtIndex:i];
                [catalogeView setPosition:CGPointMake(10 + 105*(num%CATALOGE_ON_SHELF_VERTICAL),15)];
                [cell addSubview:catalogeView];
                num++;
            }

        }

    }

    return cell;
}
```

and the Catalogue View class:

```
    @implementation CatalogeView
@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize cataloge;
- (void)dealloc {
    [cataloge release];
    [image release];
    [title release];
    [button release];
    [super dealloc];
}

+(id) make{
    NSInteger koef = 1;
    if (IPADAPP) {
        koef = 2;
    }
    CatalogeView* ctrl = [[[CatalogeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, FULL_VIEW_WIDTH * koef, FULL_VIEW_HEIGTH * koef)] autorelease];
    [ctrl addAllSubviews];
    return ctrl;

}

-(void) addAllSubviews{
    NSInteger koef = 1;
    if (IPADAPP) {
        koef = 2;
    }

    if (!title) {
        title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, FULL_VIEW_WIDTH * koef, TITLE_HEIGTH * koef)];
        [title setNumberOfLines:2];
        [title setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [title setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:9  * koef]];
        [title setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
        [title setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [self addSubview:title];
    }
    if (!image) {
        image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, TITLE_HEIGTH * koef, FULL_VIEW_WIDTH * koef, IMAGE_HEIGTH * koef)];
        [image setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [self addSubview:image ];
    }

    if (!button) {
        button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, FULL_VIEW_WIDTH * koef, FULL_VIEW_HEIGTH * koef)];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(click) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self addSubview:button ];
    }


}

-(void) addCatalogeInView:(CatalogeDbo*) newCataloge{
    self.cataloge = newCataloge;
    [title setText:cataloge.realName];
    [image setImage:[DownloadImage getImageWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", cataloge.image]]];
}

-(void) setPosition:(CGPoint) position{
    NSInteger koef = 1;
    if (IPADAPP) {
        koef = 2;
    }

    [self setFrame:CGRectMake(position.x, position.y, FULL_VIEW_WIDTH * koef, FULL_VIEW_HEIGTH * koef)];
}

-(void) click{
    if(cataloge){

        [delegate clGoInCataloge:cataloge];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: An image is worth a thousand words. Add a screenshot of your problem.

Comment: And what do you want to achieve? It is visible that the labels overlap but how would it look like in the normal case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cell height was not matching with the `subviews` `contentsize` you are adding in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Also you should use unique `Identifier` for each row. Otherwise the already created cell with the same `Identifier` "landscape-cell" was re-used and not created again .
Use the `Identifier`  something like

```
[NSString stringWithformat: "cell_%d",indexpath.row];
```

Hope you achieve the target.

Comment: any exapmle please? any one line code? what you mean by identifier? a tableviewcell or title for cell?

Answer (score 2):

Reading all this, my assumption is that you're adding `CatalogeView` multiple times and this causes the labels, buttons and images to overlap (the last two you just don't see overlapping) everytime a cell is dequeued. Instead, make a function that changes the values for the objects in `CatalogeView` and set them if it's already been added.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating new ui elements dynamically every time that the cell's will be generated. Why don't you just create a custom cell (or two, landscape and portrait) inside a new nib file. This way you can access the elements you want and the labels won't overlap because you just can set them to the position you want, inside the `InterfaceBuilder`. And you just would need to call them like :

```
[cell.label1 setText
[cell.label2 setText....
```

And keep in mind, adding additional `SubViews` to `UITableViewCells` might cause a problem. You should keep the number of subviews as low as possible so the `UITableView` doesn't get to slow. There is a good explanation in a WWDC Stream: 
[iOS App Performance: Graphics and Animations](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=238)

Answer (score 1):

You might be calculating incorrectly your frames. For Landscape or portrait mode

Answer (score 0):

if You are using a custum cell then you have to define height for row,and if you are using addsubview of cell then you have to provide correct positions of all subviews.

Answer (score 0):

write below if you still face problem

```
cell=nil;  // use this to create new cell
if (cell == nil){
      cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:
}
```

Comment: Seriously? Please indent and space your code correctly. Thousands of other people will thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that heightForRowAtIndexPath(or xib setting) returns different height than your CatalogueView which causes such overlapping. Also why not use UICollectionView(or PSTCollectionView in case you need to support iOS 5.x)?

> ! Вовка в Простоквашино и Дюймовочка блудного попугая - можно новые мультфильмы снимать. :)
>   (Some talking about Russian cartoons caused by overlapping names)